# Limit numbers after the decimal point in TOC

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, table-of-contents

In ArcMap 10.1, on the field tab there is an option to set the number of decimal places. The labels and attribute table both reflect this but not in the table of contents. Is there a way to have the same thing show up in the table of contents?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you mean for the symbology. Then you can right click on the layer, open the properties tab, right click on the label header and open the label properties window. This will allow you to change the label format.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do but don't seem to have that option to edit the number format. Maybe I am using a different ArcMap version? I am symbolizing under Categories, Unique values, many, but I could not make it work under Quantities either.

Comment: It's tested for 10.1 and quantities. Under categories it does not work : you need to manually edit each label.